# Somar ganhos de um mesmo funcionário

Tags: javascript, planilha

Estou tentando somar todos os ganhos de um funcionario(soma cumulativa), mas não estou conseguindo. O codigo está a seguir:

```
function teto() {    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp; //seta a planilha 
  var planilhaAtiva = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //torna-a ativa
  var abaAtiva = planilhaAtiva.getActiveSheet(); //seta a aba ativa

  for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
    var cpf = [i][3];
    var valor = [i][11];

    if (cpf = cpf+1) {
      valor = valor + (valor + 1);
      abaAtiva.getRange(i,13).setValue(valor); 

    }
  }
}
```

Explicando: eu tenho uma coluna com cpfs agrupados de vários funcionários, e outra coluna com o valor da comissão q ele recebe. Se o cpf de uma linha for igual ao cpf da linha de baixo, ele faz a soma[image: veja a tabela exemplo aqui]. Ele deve fazer essa soma enquanto os CPFs forem iguais, e colocar esse valor em uma nova coluna - C, SOMA.
Se não for igual, eu não quero que ele some ao anterior, mas que inicie uma nova soma com o novo conjunto de valores do mesmo cpf.

Comment: Você precisa colocar dois iguais no if. Além disso, a condição está errada. Deveria ser: `if(cpf == [i+1][3])` Outra coisa é que a sintaxe está errada também. colocar `[i][3]` direto está incorreto. Não conheço essa biblioteca, mas deveria ser: `abaAtiva[i][3]`. Logo: `if(cpf == abaAtiva[i+1][3])`

Comment: Isso está certo. Não é javascript puro, mas googleappscript, gas, e usa essa notação.